# searching address (geocode.search.hereapi.com) weird behavior

Tags: here-api, geocode, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I'm using https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q to search for address in USA.

When I give **q=765 Rive** I get lot of address but the moment when I give **765 River** My results are very restricted and I get only very less responses and which does not include lot of addresses I got in the previous q search.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check now. When I trying with the postman .It is giving the same number count in the response.

https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=765 Rive&apikey={your_api_key}

https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=765 River&apikey={your_api_key}

And Please follow below document, which explains how we can formulate a qualified query.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-geocode-qualified.html